# ANTLR and Literate Programming

Tags: antlr

I'm trying to write a parser for a simple, literate language -- with structure similar to PHP. The source might look something like:

```
blurb blurb blurb
[[ if mode == 5 ]]
then blurb blurb blurb
[[ else ]]
else blurb blurb blurb
[[ end ]]
```

The non-code sections -- those not nested in `[[ ]]` -- don't follow any syntax rules. It's just natural language.

However, I'm not sure how to write a grammar rules to match the non-code text. I'd welcome any help on how I might do this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the ANTLR folks identified this task long ago. I guess what I'm trying to build is an island grammar, where islands of syntax appear within a sea of text that has no rules applied.

Chapter 12 of Parr's Definitive ANTLR 4 Reference led me to a solution, which involves switching between sublexers when I hit a delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

You can treat the non code text like comments.

To indicate whether it is a code or comment block you can introduce 
some special symbols. Eg /* blub blub  */ or something like that.

so your parser grammer could look like this:

```
program : program | 
          if_statement | 
          non-code

if_statement : '[[' 'if' expression ']]' 
               ...

expressen : var OPERATOR var;

var : LITERAL; 

non-code : '/*' any_text*'*/

any_text : LITERAL | DIGIT | SPECIAL_CHAR
```

where ANY_TEXT is a lexer rule for

```
 SPECIAL_CHAR  : '-'|'+' ....

 OPERATOR : '<' | '>' ....     


 LITERAL : (CHAR | DIGIT)+ 

 fragment CHAR : ('A'..'Z' | 'a'..'z')+

 fragement DIGIT : ('0'..'9')+;
```

EDIT due to comment:

Ok then maybe you can try to make some kind of preprocessing or of chaining parsers. I just made something similar some time ago. In your case i would just parse the input string with simple REGEX rule and look for the coded parts and then internaly add some kind of tag to the non-coded part.

```
 Input:

 blub blub blah
 [[ if express ]] 
 blah blah blub
```

--> Preprocess

```
 <non-code>blub blub blah</non-code>
 [[ if express ]] 
 <non-code>blah blah blub</non-code>
```

--> Paring using ANTLR Parser and Lexer

You may have also a look to TreeParser where you can reduce your input grammar to the parts you wish to evaluate by leaving unnecessary 
tokens.

Comment: I'd considered this, but the explicit demarcation of non-code is something I wish to avoid. The ratio of natural language to code is going to be high, so I'd like to make it as easy as possible to write the non-code sections.

Answer (score 0):

In looking at the way GHC manages literate Haskell files, I think the best approach may be a preprocessing step that "deliterates" the source by turning the non-code sections into something that is more formally specified.

Maybe I have an emit function that takes as a parameter the non-code text. I can preprocess the source with something like:

```
src.gsub /(\A|\]\])(.*?)(\Z|\[\[)/ 'emit(\2)'
```

Comment: Yeah right. Preprocessing is a solution. You can do it within the Parser or Lexer rules but maybe it is simpler. Because you know when the coded part starts. In any case you will always have the problem that some character sequence is not allowed because it indicates the beginning or ending of a special block. Thats why escape charaters are introduced to many languages HTML, XML which tell the parser to interpret the litaral as simple char and not as Parser rule.